# Compare multiple rows from the same table in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
CREATE TABLE #im  ( SId int,  Reporting_Year_Id int );
GO        
INSERT #im (SId, Reporting_Year_Id) VALUES (1,2011)
INSERT #im (SId, Reporting_Year_Id) VALUES (2,2011)
INSERT #im (SId, Reporting_Year_Id) VALUES (3,2011)
GO

CREATE TABLE #im1 ( SID int,  PID int, Release int, Legal int, Seq int);
GO
INSERT #im1 (SID, PID, Release, Legal, Seq) VALUES (1,10005,1,18,1) --Trans_Type should be 'A'
INSERT #im1 (SID, PID, Release, Legal, Seq) VALUES (1,10005,1,10,1) --Trans_Type should be 'C'
INSERT #im1 (SID, PID, Release, Legal, Seq) VALUES (2,10005,1,18,1) --Trans_Type should be ' '
INSERT #im1 (SID, PID, Release, Legal, Seq) VALUES (3,10006,1,20,1) --Trans_Type should be 'A'

GO

declare @iCurrentFileId int
set @iCurrentFileId = 2; 

WITH current_file as
(
      select * from #im1 where SID = @iCurrentFileId
)    
, previous_file as
(
      select * from #im1 where SID = @iCurrentFileId -1 
)
select c.SID, c.PID,c.Legal,c.Release,c.Seq,p.SID,
    case when p.SID IS  null then 'A' 
         else 'C' end as 'transaction_type'
from current_file c left outer join previous_file p on p.PID = c.PID and c.Seq = p.Seq
```

I need to set the transaction_Type to:

'A' if all records except SID doesn't exist in the previous SID

'C' if all records except SID are different from the previous SID

' ' if all records are the same except SID

How to do that? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to perform an update on the temp table based on your business rules, then return the results.  For example, this would satisfy transaction type A:

```
declare @im table(previousID int, previousSID int, recentID int, recentSID int, transaction_type varchar(50))

insert into @im(previousID, previousSID, recentID, recentSID, transaction_type) values (1,2,7,9,'')
insert into @im(previousID, previousSID, recentID, recentSID, transaction_type) values (2,2,8,2,'')
insert into @im(previousID, previousSID, recentID, recentSID, transaction_type) values (3,3,9,3,'')
insert into @im(previousID, previousSID, recentID, recentSID, transaction_type) values (4,3,10,3,'')
insert into @im(previousID, previousSID, recentID, recentSID, transaction_type) values (5,4,11,4,'')
insert into @im(previousID, previousSID, recentID, recentSID, transaction_type) values (6,4,12,4,'')


/* 'A' if all records in the most recent SID doesn't exist in the previous SID */
update im
set transaction_type = 'A - 9 is not one of the previous SIDs'
from @im im
where im.recentSID not in (
    select distinct previousSID from @im
)

/* add additional updates based on your business rules... */

/* finally return the results */

select * from @im
```

Comment: Merritt, Thank you for the answer. I realized that I didn't explain properly so I updated my question. Could you look at it again and let me know the same? Thanks, Thomas